# how to obtain mobile number of own device in android?

Tags: android

I want to retreive mobile number of device programatically. My code is:-

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String strMobileNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

and I have set `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in AndroidManifest.xml file. This is working on emulator but on actual device with eclair version, it is returning empty string. Is there any other way to get mobile no?

Comment: Accept answers to your previous questions. Try to format the code you post by using the {} button above the text area when you type the question.

Comment: AFAIK, not possible cz Network operators dont use mobile number, they communicate through IMSI and TIMSI so mobile number is not stored in mobile as well as on SIM... favouriting; me too have same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reliable way to "retreive mobile number of device programatically", AFAIK. `getLine1Number()` reports the number supplied by the SIM card for GSM phones, and the mobile number does not need to be on the SIM card.

Comment: But for SMS which are sent out[outgoing SMS], how system sends out mobile no. of sender as mobile no. is not saved on SIM and network operators use IMSI no.?

Comment: Isn't there a method to get the mobile number when an incoming call is received or an outgoing call is made?