# How to obtain Phone Number in Android?

Tags: android

This is an extension to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329216/how-to-obtain-mobile-number-of-own-device-in-android). Now I quote [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)

> **There is no reliable way to retrieve mobile number of device programatically.** The only option remaining and I can think of is getting user to input for the phone number.

My question is how to check if the phone number entered by the user is correct for these and any more possibilities which I cannot think now:

1. The number entered by the user is of the same device the app has been downloaded on.
2. User did not make any typographical error while entering the number
3. User did not enter any local calling code like leading 0

I have spend sufficient time on StackOverflow and web and this is not a duplicate question.

I will appreciate any help, clues or suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to obtain mobile number of own device in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329216/how-to-obtain-mobile-number-of-own-device-in-android)

Comment: @DanielA.White Hi, you are saying the the question is duplicate of same question it is referring to and is extension of.

Comment: @DanielA.White Does people answer to comments? This question requires fresh thinking and opinions from the community and can be useful to many App developers in future.

Comment: This question is nonsense given the answers to the previous one.  If you could "check that it is correct", you could get the number in the first place and wouldn't need to ask the user to input it.

Comment: @Barak Can you please clarify you comment for me?

Comment: My apologies, I thought you asked the question you reference at the top.  So change the pronouns in my first comment :).  Anyway, in the question you reference at the top, the person asked about getting the phones # programatically and was told it wasn't reliably possible.  So how are you going to "check" that the number the user inputs "is of the same device the app has been downloaded on"...  to check it you would have to be able to pull the phone number from the device reliably, and you can't.  You've essentially asked the same question again.

Comment: @Barak Your assumption that no other possibility exits is limiting your thoughts and hence your deduction that the **you have essentially asked the same question again** is also wrong. For example there may be some api (which we don't know about) against which we can check the user input.

Comment: CommonsWare would have mentioned that in the other question if it existed.  As he's written several books about Android and obviously keeps up with current developments in the area, I kinda trust what he says.  If your hypothetical API existed, you wouldn't need to get the user's input, now would you?  Because that API would be able to pull the # from the phone.  It's a logical fallacy you've engaged in. You cannot check the users input without having something to check it against, and the only thing you could check it against (in this scenario) is the phone # pulled from the phone itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.The number entered by the user is of the same device the app has been downloaded on.

Again this is something kind of impossible to test, else the Tricky way mentioned by @neteinstein

---

> 2.User did not make any typographical error while entering the number
>
> 3.User did not enter any local calling code like leading 0

I think you still not aware of this **[library](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)** by google,used for *Parsing/formatting/validating phone numbers for all countries/regions of the world.*

Using that you can achive your other 2 solutions.I think.

---

Link : http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to possibly spend some user money you can send an SMS to yourself (number inputted by the user) and check if it arrives.

If it does, the number is correct. If not... either you have no network, or the number is incorrect.

I don't even think the phone has the number visibility, according to my experience with Mobile Operators, only on their side they have that visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know about nr1, I think you can solve problem nr 2 and 3 quite easily by analysing the number while its a String. That way you can easily check what characters it contains and what positions these characters are on.
I hope this helps.

Greets,
Wottah